# how to reload view controllers in tabbar while switching in swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, tabbar

need to switch between view controllers of tabbar controller and each time appearing, view controllers need to be reloaded

connected view controllers with tabbar in storyboard and they are navigating too but I need to reload like the view controller is being pushed

Comment: Add a "refresh" code in `viewDidAppear()`?